# My result came out "None" when i try to use BeautifulSoup to do web-scraping. Any idea?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My result kept on showing `"None"` and `[]` when I change to `soup.findAll`. Any idea why can't I get the result?

This is the link I wanted to retrieve the information from.
https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=%E3%80%90local%20ready%20stock%E3%80%91%E3%80%90nero%E3%80%91(00-15)%20anna%20sleepwear%20short%20baju%20tidur%20pyjamas%20pajamas%20sleepwear&page=0&pdpL3Category=100226&shop=426096286&sortBy=sales

````
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=%E3%80%90local%20ready%20stock%E3%80%91%E3%80%90nero%E3%80%91(00-15)%20anna%20sleepwear%20short%20baju%20tidur%20pyjamas%20pajamas%20sleepwear&page=0&pdpL3Category=100226&shop=426096286&sortBy=sales'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = soup.find("div", attrs = {"class":"_2VIlt8"})
print(containers)```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is no object with class "_2VIlt8" in the "soup" object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link href="//cf.shopee.com.my/" rel="preconnect"/>
<link href="//deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/" rel="preconnect"/>
<link href="//cv.shopee.com.my/" rel="preconnect"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="0b3bb160bb1090d00e8a2871c7023c666c67e8e1" name="shopee:git-sha"/>
<meta content="rw-v3.94.0" name="shopee:version"/>
<script>
window.__PAGE_ID__ = 12;
        window.__LOCALE__ = 'MY';
        window.__ENV__ = 'live';
        window.__ASSETS__ = {"CCMS_FEATURE_TOGGLE":{"ALL_CATEGORIES_HOMEPAGE_ENTRANCE":{"default":false,"TW":true,"VN":true,"PH":true,"MY":true,"ID":true},"AMP_CATEGORY_PAGE":{"default":true},"BUNDLE_DEALS":{"default":true},"BUNDLE_DEAL_11":{"default":true},"COMMENT_BUTTON_WHITELIST":{"default":[{"username":"shopeesg","userid":11918,"shopid":11918},{"username":"shopee_mamak","userid":145427,"shopid":145423},{"username":"shopeetreats","userid":429435,"shopid":429375},{"username":"shopeeth","userid":727272,"shopid":726766},{"username":"shopee_tw","userid":470473,"shopid":470357},{"username":"shopee_beauty","userid":26046080,"shopid":26044744},{"username":"shopeeid","userid":1290517,"shopid":1289539},{"username":"shopeevn","userid":1756170,"shopid":1754914},{"username":"shopeevn","userid":2216427,"shopid":2215148}]},"DAILY_DISCOVER_TABS":{"TH":true,"default":false,"TW":true,"VN":true,"BR":true,"SG":true},"FEATURED_COLLECTIONS":{"default":true},"FILTER_COD":{"default":false,"MY":true,"ID":true},"FILTER_CREDIT_CARD":{"default":false,"TW":true},"FILTER_DRAWER_3PL":{"default":true,"MY":false,"TH":false},"FILTER_DRAWER_INSTALLMENT":{"default":false,"ID":true},"FILTER_DRAWER_LOCATION":{"default":true},"FILTER_DRAWER_MALL":{"default":true,"BR":false},"FILTER_LOCATION_PHASE_2":{"default":false,"ID":true,"VN":true},"FILTER_LOWEST_PRICE_GUARANTEE":{"default":true,"TW":false},"FILTER_SERVICE_BY_SHOPEE":{"default":false,"TW":true,"ID":true},"FILTER_SHORTCUT_3PL":{"default":false,"ID":true,"VN":true},"FILTER_SHORTCUT_COD":{"default":false,"MY":true},"FILTER_SHORTCUT_LOCATION":{"default":false,"TW":true,"VN":true,"MY":true,"PH":true,"SG":true,"ID":true},"FILTER_SHORTCUT_MALL":{"default":true,"BR":false},"FLASH_SALE_CATEGORIES":{"default":true},"FLOATING_ICON":{"default":true},"FROM_SAME_SHOP":{"default":true},"GRAY_SKIN":{"default":false},"GROUP_BUY":{"default":false,"TW":true,"ID":true},"GROUP_BUY_ONGOING_GROUP":{"default":true},"GTM_TRACKING":{"default":true},"INSTALLMENT":{"default":true},"ITEM_CARD_DISPLAY_LOCATION":{"default":true},"ITEM_LIST_ADULT_CHECK":{"default":false,"TW":true,"ID":true,"VN":true,"MX":true},"NEW_ADS_TRACKER":{"default":100,"TW":50,"ID":100},"NEW_SELLER_PENALTY":{"default":true},"NEW_YOU_MAY_ALSO_LIKE":{"default":true},"OFFICIAL_SHOP":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_BRAND_LABEL":{"default":true,"MY":false,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_LABEL_INLINE":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_LANDING":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_MALL_URL":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_SELLING_POINT":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OFFICIAL_SHOP_THEME":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"OPC_UX_IMPROVEMENT":{"default":false,"MY":false,"BR":true,"TH":false},"ORDER_PAID_PAGE_BUTTON":{"default":{"url":"/","title":"Home Page"},"MY":{"url":"/","title":"Home Page"},"ID":{"url":"/","title":"Halaman Utama"},"TH":{"url":"/","title":"โฮมเพจ"}},"PERSONALIZED_TRENDING_SEARCH":{"default":true},"PRODUCT_CARD_V1_4":{"default":{"A":[0,100],"B":[100,100]}},"PRODUCT_CARD_V1_4_location":{"default":[0,100],"PH":[0,0],"SG":[0,0]},"PRODUCT_CATALOGUE":{"default":true},"PRODUCT_DIKELOLA_SHOPEE":{"default":false,"ID":true},"PRODUCT_SOLD_COUNT_CAP":{"default":false,"ID":true},"RECOMMEND_ITEM":{"default":true},"RN_MICRO_SITE":{"default":true},"RW_ONE_PAGE_CHECKOUT":{"default":true},"RW_OPC_UX_SHIPPING_RECOMMENDATIONS":{"default":false,"MY":true,"TH":true},"RW_OPC_UX_TOTAL_PAYMENT_STICKY":{"default":false,"SG":true,"VN":true,"TH":true,"PH":true,"MY":true},"SEARCHPAGE_MYADS_ENTRANCE":{"default":false,"TW":true,"ID":true,"VN":true,"TH":true},"SEARCH_PREFILL":{"default":false},"SHOPEE_BUDDY":{"default":false,"TH":true},"SHOP_VOUCHERS":{"default":true},"SHOW_OFFICIAL_SHOP_LABEL":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"SHOW_OPC_WARNING":{"default":false,"TW":false},"SHOW_SOLD_COUNT":{"default":true,"BR":false,"IN":false},"SKINNY_BANNER":{"default":true},"SLASH_PRICE":{"default":false,"TW":true,"SG":true},"SUPPORT_CHECKOUT_GEO_LOCATION":{"default":false,"MY":true,"ID":true,"VN":true,"TH":true},"THREE_PL_MASKING":{"default":false,"VN":true,"TH":true,"PH":true,"MY":true,"ID":true},"TIER_VARIATIONS_MAX_COMBINATIONS":{"default":50},"TIER_VARIATIONS_MAX_OPTIONS_PER_VARIATION":{"default":20,"TW":50},"TOP_PRODUCTS":{"default":true},"TWO_TIER_VARIATION":{"default":true},"TW_KYC_POPUP_WEB":{"default":false,"TW":true},"WALLET_AUTO_WITHDRAWAL_SETTING":{"default":false,"SG":true,"PH":true,"MY":true,"VN":true},"WALLET_WITHDRAWAL_FEE":{"default":true},"WELCOME_PACKAGE_POPUP_FIRST":{"TH":true,"default":false,"TW":true,"VN":true,"BR":true,"IN":true,"ID":true}},"DL_ENABLED_MALL_REGIONS":["SG","MY","ID","TH","VN","PH","TW"],"FESTIVAL_SKIN":{"data":[{"status":1,"mobile_top_nav_bar":{"color":"white","background_image_long":"f1e536fb82c5e7dfbb1677235da1b2a9","display":1,"background_image_standard":"61538fee92cf7ba3dfe970a7fb22393d"},"end":1633881599,"name":"10.10 Brands Festival 2021","pc":{"banner":{"image_type":"fs","image":"5a6d6505b195a28c76db09dcabaae569","display_height":800,"display_width":3400},"display":1},"mobile":{"display":1,"custom_header":{"CATEGORY":{"background_image":"c45805256917b040eb496924f20f5165"},"DAILY_DISCOVER":{"background_image":"8bceab95ba1073fe724b3f508d891879"}},"apply_to_pc":false},"start":1632067200,"mtime":1631246358,"operator":"jamie.wong@shopee.com","id":29}]},"FESTIVAL_SKIN_V2":{"data":null,"error":104,"error_msg":""},"MART_CONFIG":{"shop":{"shopid":52784309,"username":"shopee_mart"},"header":null},"PAGE_MANIFEST":{"mobilemall-addondeal-aod":null,"mobilemall-addondeal-pwg":null,"mobilemall-addondeal-pwp":null,"mobilemall-allcampaigns":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/main.c6dac7c15b192fc374cc.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/main.5ab41101cb06cae5b821.js","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/0c12f068b146c4a98f693f3ae58e8066.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/9bc15954e413f94bf98e9e1b3464aa7d.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/2d2f4d024b2fc995c08cb39e75d2a3d8.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/4544112e5c776de74a8c10b17cf190b3.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/e2b3786052761681ad7d7c68658c8f2e.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/152142ae83d2e2618fcec60aced9d9aa.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/c91e4be3268ecdcf46a9b1307baafd62.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/608164e08f25f953c931cb5a51afcd47.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/b5fce144738a62402e9cce503ca372cb.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/2d29cf7aa1c5664f08875861e5091350.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/43352d53c736a63d16cca2d8d23ba024.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/e87333f3fb0bb1b97ae324972db8997c.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/40fbcc5f8becdf611565163b0d8e51a6.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/1f42147787fd4e281353bfab7adcf3cd.png","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/allcampaigns/a045979df9cef34b17749cecd3f4d8ce.png"],"mobilemall-cart":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/cart/mobilemall-cart.142ddcfac3b607560ba4.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/cart/mobilemall-cart.fa2e8934aa387ac2ade3.js"],"mobilemall-chatbroadcast":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/chatbroadcast/main.c8d0530e6efca56dc443.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/chatbroadcast/main.fcf3877cc84f06ebe0de.js"],"mobilemall-coinsrewardpage":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/coinsrewardpage/main.2964cc0919e5201f2490.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/coinsrewardpage/main.57e8e352b6a436e69a7c.js"],"mobilemall-dailycheckin":null,"mobilemall-flashsale":null,"mobilemall-groupbuy":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/groupbuy/main.edeb4608e29acdecbafe.js"],"mobilemall-microtestb":null,"mobilemall-orderlist":null,"mobilemall-paymentfe":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/paymentfe/main.dd70fc7434d4a0cd4d53.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/paymentfe/main.4123ca9d1cffd480984c.js"],"mobilemall-return":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/return/mobilemall-return.5d2aab59ad77d7da428b.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/return/mobilemall-return.6607729715602abc0af9.js"],"mobilemall-sclp":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/sclp/main.e67aace5bef57bee8628.js"],"mobilemall-shop":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/shop/mobilemall-shop.f39ad25f1166852c1e27.js"],"mobilemall-shopmainbrowseitems":["https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/shopmainbrowseitems/mobilemall-shopmainbrowseitems.f45402213dd21f09fae8.css","https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/shopmainbrowseitems/mobilemall-shopmainbrowseitems.e1c2d6e8fbe7f4b35a5b.js"]},"TRANSIFY_COLLECTION_MAPPING":{"zh-hans-live-147":1593681375,"zh-hans-live-118":1629699561,"zh-hans-live-113":1631527733,"zh-hans-live-111":1616125970,"en-live-73":1622801602,"en-live-242":1627270123,"en-live-243":1631513337,"en-live-246":1624414851,"en-live-113":1631527733,"en-live-111":1616125970,"en-live-118":1631895842,"zh-hans-live-18":1602842595,"zh-hans-live-10":1593679634,"zh-hans-live-17":1630573507,"zh-hans-live-16":1628579824,"zh-hans-live-15":1629456340,"zh-hans-live-14":1631529604,"zh-hans-live-343":1629379235,"zh-hans-live-340":1631764148,"zh-hans-live-294":1625034583,"zh-hans-live-290":1625112256,"zh-hans-live-292":1620614303,"en-live-85":1593681029,"en-live-83":1593681068,"zh-hans-live-128":1597284092,"en-live-239":1630038201,"en-live-235":1629704864,"en-live-231":1608028928,"en-live-343":1629379235,"en-live-340":1631764148,"en-live-167":1597389538,"en-live-166":1597141880,"zh-hans-live-287":1625112271,"zh-hans-live-136":1626094301,"zh-hans-live-131":1629964288,"zh-hans-live-132":1593680126,"zh-hans-live-138":1598497753,"en-live-224":1607486489,"en-live-223":1625034613,"zh-hans-live-31":1593679081,"zh-hans-live-30":1630917647,"zh-hans-live-33":1629791271,"en-live-43":1622446227,"en-live-42":1593681397,"en-live-40":1609387239,"en-live-47":1629371684,"en-live-214":1610345716,"en-live-141":1593680091,"en-live-140":1618451980,"en-live-143":1628839525,"en-live-145":1593681387,"en-live-147":1593681375,"zh-hans-live-20":1627613962,"zh-hans-live-21":1624422925,"zh-hans-live-27":1631527816,"zh-hans-live-28":1631781735,"zh-hans-live-29":1626435975,"en-live-33":1629791271,"en-live-30":1630917647,"en-live-31":1593679081,"en-live-206":1606814335,"en-live-204":1629715012,"en-live-209":1624359997,"en-live-158":1616125911,"en-live-155":1603130160,"en-live-151":1626853515,"zh-hans-live-258":1620386859,"zh-hans-live-254":1619065010,"zh-hans-live-256":1626649601,"zh-hans-live-257":1630988567,"en-live-306":1630926289,"en-live-27":1631527816,"en-live-21":1624422925,"en-live-20":1627613962,"en-live-29":1626435975,"en-live-28":1631781735,"en-live-256":1626649601,"en-live-301":1623998730,"zh-hans-live-83":1593681068,"zh-hans-live-243":1631167637,"zh-hans-live-242":1627270123,"zh-hans-live-246":1624414851,"en-live-10":1593679634,"en-live-15":1629456340,"en-live-16":1628579824,"en-live-316":1623648312,"en-live-310":1625736696,"en-live-311":1622803477,"zh-hans-live-277":1625112228,"zh-hans-live-184":1599448355,"zh-hans-live-189":1603704314,"en-live-321":1624941198,"en-live-326":1630912623,"en-live-184":1599448355,"en-live-189":1603704314,"zh-hans-live-129":1627271325,"en-live-8":1631868546,"zh-hans-live-85":1593681029,"zh-hans-live-263":1631698631,"zh-hans-live-265":1630033490,"zh-hans-live-268":1628760922,"zh-hans-live-255":1631087713,"en-live-330":1631527733,"zh-hans-live-214":1610345716,"en-live-18":1602842595,"zh-hans-live-321":1624941198,"zh-hans-live-326":1630912623,"zh-hans-live-140":1618451980,"zh-hans-live-141":1593680091,"zh-hans-live-143":1628839525,"zh-hans-live-145":1593681387,"en-live-14":1631529604,"en-live-17":1630573507,"en-live-290":1625112256,"en-live-292":1620614303,"en-live-294":1625034583,"zh-hans-live-206":1606814335,"zh-hans-live-204":1629715012,"zh-hans-live-209":1624359997,"zh-hans-live-330":1631527733,"zh-hans-live-151":1626853515,"zh-hans-live-155":1603130160,"zh-hans-live-158":1616125911,"en-live-287":1625112271,"zh-hans-live-9":1630907010,"zh-hans-live-8":1631868546,"zh-hans-live-239":1630038201,"zh-hans-live-231":1608028928,"zh-hans-live-235":1629704864,"en-live-318":1627460688,"zh-hans-live-306":1630926289,"zh-hans-live-301":1623998730,"zh-hans-live-166":1597141880,"zh-hans-live-167":1597389538,"en-live-258":1631711470,"en-live-277":1625112228,"en-live-129":1627271325,"en-live-128":1597284092,"zh-hans-live-47":1629371684,"zh-hans-live-40":1609387239,"zh-hans-live-42":1593681397,"zh-hans-live-43":1622446227,"zh-hans-live-224":1607486489,"zh-hans-live-223":1625034613,"zh-hans-live-310":1625736696,"zh-hans-live-316":1623648312,"zh-hans-live-318":1627460688,"en-live-263":1631711435,"en-live-265":1630033490,"en-live-268":1628760922,"en-live-138":1598497753,"en-live-131":1629964288,"en-live-132":1593680126,"en-live-136":1626094301,"zh-hans-live-73":1622801602,"en-live-9":1630907010,"zh-hans-live-108":1628760922,"zh-hans-live-107":1593679622,"zh-hans-live-100":1626676223,"zh-hans-live-101":1626648867,"zh-hans-live-102":1626649308,"en-live-255":1631087713,"en-live-254":1619065010,"en-live-257":1630988567,"en-live-108":1628760922,"en-live-107":1593679622,"en-live-101":1626648867,"en-live-100":1626676223,"en-live-102":1626649308},"TRANSIFY_MAPPING":{"id-live":1631851161,"es-es-live":1631781100,"pl-live":1631951034,"hi-live":1631781100,"ms-my-live":1631851161,"pt-br-live":1631851161,"vi-live":1631851161,"es-cl-live":1631851161,"fr-live":1631781100,"es-mx-live":1631851161,"es-co-live":1631851161,"en-live":1631851161,"es-ar-live":1631781100,"zh-hans-live":1631851161,"zh-hant-live":1631851161,"th-live":1631851161}};
</script>
<script>function isModernBrowser(){return!!(window.fetch&&Object.values&&Object.entries&&[].flat)}isModernBrowser()||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/polyfill.927947bae093cb19384b.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>function showBody(){document&&document.body&&(document.body.style.visibility="visible")}function isSupermarketPath(t){return"/supermarket"===t||"/supermarket/"===t}var SHORT_URL_MAX_LENGTH=256,pathname=location&&location.pathname,origin=(location&&location.origin||"").replace(/^(https?:\/\/)lite\./,(function(t,e){return e}));if("/"!==pathname&&!isSupermarketPath(pathname)&&pathname.length<SHORT_URL_MAX_LENGTH&&""===location.hash&&0===pathname.lastIndexOf("/")){document&&document.body&&(document.body.style.visibility="hidden"),setTimeout(showBody,5e3);var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open("GET",origin+"/api/v4/pages/is_short_url/?path="+pathname.replace("/","")),xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json"),xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json"),xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4===this.readyState)if(200===this.status){var t=JSON.parse(this.responseText);t&&t.data&&t.data.url?location.href=t.data.url:showBody()}else showBody()},xhr.send()}</script>
<script>if(window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)},ga.l=+new Date,window.PerformanceObserver)try{var observer=new window.PerformanceObserver((function(e){for(var r=e.getEntries(),n=0;n<r.length;n++){var a=r[n],i=a.name,t=Math.round(a.startTime+a.duration);ga("send",{hitType:"timing",timingCategory:"Performance Metrics",timingVar:i,timingValue:t})}}));observer.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]})}catch(e){}</script>
<script>"loading"in HTMLImageElement.prototype?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(function(){document.querySelectorAll("img[loading].lazyload").forEach((function(e){e.src=e.dataset.src}))})):document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/polyfill.6eeeee64c6017caa20b5.js"><\/script>')</script><script>window.MutationObserver||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/polyfill.909f7922f04e46f7c94f.js"><\/script>')</script><script>!function(){var e=document.createElement("div").style;e.setProperty&&e.setProperty("--x","x"),e.getPropertyValue&&"x"===e.getPropertyValue("--x")||(document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/polyfill.ba71afacee21a231fd9f.js"><\/script>'),document.write("<script>window.cssVars({preserveVars:!0,watch:!0});<\/script>"))}()</script>
<script>dataLayer=[],function(e,t,a,o,r){var n="no-delay";try{if(localStorage){var m=localStorage.getItem("GTM_DELAY");m||(m=Math.floor(100*Math.random())+"",localStorage.setItem("GTM_DELAY",m)),(m=parseInt(m,10))&&!Number.isNaN(m)&&m<100&&(n="delay")}}catch(e){console.log(e)}var c="delay"===n?5e3:0;e[o]=e[o]||[],e[o].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js",country:"my",userGroup:n}),setTimeout((function(){var e=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],o=t.createElement(a);o.async=!0,o.src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WJZQSJF",e.parentNode.insertBefore(o,e)}),c)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer")</script>
<script>var spt=[]</script>
<link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/entry-modules.f955bbd094df60279329.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/bundle.9179ab9be775ffa49e4e.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<meta content="#EE4D2D" name="theme-color"><link href="/m/assets/manifest.64961108192778c454d263d59ac73576.json" rel="manifest"><meta content="yes" name="mobile-web-app-capable"><meta content="yes" name="apple-touch-fullscreen"><meta content="Shopee" name="apple-mobile-web-app-title"><meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/><meta content="default" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_icon_120x120.9c9cd4366011639d86dcf03856866b39.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" size="120x120"><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_icon_180x180.350d4cdc7ba40b87541691005bda74c5.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" size="180x180"><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_640x1136.44f3b1919faea215b1e8a8f33bc85eb2.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_750x1334.e7f516f762373cc6c316d37455600b8a.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1242x2208.0030ddfcb47d1a8f7f34ea1f488e063d.png" media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1125x2436.d03df48b337e7e7f19d94203a800123b.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_828x1792.848d89109908599fcf6edf6e0b7c6cde.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1242x2688.806794fa2096fd0d63f138f9380033ab.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1080x2340.b159e955714fc4bfcee0415d7a196559.png" media="(device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 780px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1170x2532.7d66e217dfb6824abb4829a8c0092554.png" media="(device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_1284x2778.91b92b6b72c0355991793e6f3bf45eaf.png" media="(device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/bundle.24388f88eeed96734c10.js" rel="preload"/><link as="style" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/bundle.9179ab9be775ffa49e4e.css" rel="preload"/><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/entry-modules.5b368a048c5908338df0.js" rel="preload"/><link as="style" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/entry-modules.f955bbd094df60279329.css" rel="preload"/><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/modules.cae3a06e7fd68892cda3.js" rel="preload"/><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/webpack-runtime.1f7ecaaf243e950acd83.js" rel="preload"/><link as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/stm-sg-live/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/ms-my.1631851161.json" rel="preload"><style data-href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/48035.9e403afba91baa85704b.css">:root{--safe-area-inset-bottom:0;--safe-area-inset-bottom:env(safe-area-inset-bottom,0)}.scroll-to-top{cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;position:fixed;right:.875rem;bottom:.875rem;z-index:8999;width:2.6875rem;height:2.6875rem}.scroll-to-top--with-safe-area-inset-bottom{-webkit-transform:translateY(calc(-1*env(safe-area-inset-bottom, 0)));transform:translateY(calc(-1*env(safe-area-inset-bottom, 0)));-webkit-transform:translateY(calc(-1*var(--safe-area-inset-bottom, 0)));transform:translateY(calc(-1*var(--safe-area-inset-bottom, 0)))}.search-page .stardust-spinner{position:fixed;top:50%;left:0;right:0;margin-top:-.5rem}.search-page .stardust-spinner__main{background:transparent}.theme--ofs .navbar-generic__back,.theme--ofs .navbar-generic__menu,.theme--ofs .navbar-search__filter{fill:#d0011b!important;stroke:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .navbar-search__filter-text,.theme--ofs .stardust-tabs-header__tab--active{color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .stardust-tabs-header__tab--active .stardust-icon{fill:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .stardust-tabs-header__tab-indicator{background-color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--selected .stardust-button{border-color:#d0011b!important;color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--selected .stardust-icon{color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--selected.stardust-button,.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--selected.stardust-button:hover{border-color:#d0011b!important;color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--expanded .filter-bar-item__inner-text,.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--expanded .stardust-button{color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-item--expanded .stardust-icon{fill:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-popover__item--selected{color:#d0011b!important;border-color:#d0011b!important}.theme--ofs .filter-bar-popover__row--selected .filter-bar-popover__row-inner,.theme--ofs .filter-bar-popover__row--selected .stardust-icon,.theme--ofs .infinite-scroll__loading,.theme--ofs .item-card-list__no-more,.theme--ofs .search-items-footer-hint__link{color:#d0011b!important}</style><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/7914.c0c84ce8f4c6a52c61d1.js" rel="preload"><link as="script" href="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/PageSearch.9e403afba91baa85704b.js" rel="preload"><script>
    window.__LOCALE__ = 'MY';
    window.__ENV__ = 'live';
  </script><script type="text/shopee-vc">{"variates":{"ls.FJ":1,"sch.DV":1,"dp.GA":0,"sch.JZ":1,"sch.GN":0,"bot.HT":3,"bi.IG":1,"bot.FP":1,"dd.IO":0,"sch.GR":3,"sch.FC":2,"sch.DO":0,"bot.KN":0,"credit.DN":0,"sch.DZ":8,"sch.ES":2,"sch.JO":0,"sch.BZ":0,"sch.GG":0,"sch.EZ":0,"fee.CA":0,"sch.FR":0,"bot.FZ":2,"sch.IZ":0,"sch.EG":2,"sch.GV":2,"bi.HN":2,"bot.KI":1,"sch.FW":3,"sch.EM":0,"ord.DM":0,"sch.DF":0,"sch.EP":2,"sch.IL":0,"sch.GK":0,"sch.FN":4,"dp.IH":1,"fee.BX":1,"sch.GE":0,"sch.IP":0,"bot.HR":3,"sch.DY":1,"ord.IX":1,"bi.HO":2,"voucher.ID":5,"fee.CB":0,"ord.HA":2,"bot.LI":2,"sch.GF":0,"sch.KC":0,"fee.EU":1,"fee.BB":0,"sch.GT":0,"bot.HE":1,"sch.IN":0,"voucher.CM":2,"sch.DS":1,"sch.DP":4,"ls.FK":2,"sch.JQ":0,"fee.AV":1,"sch.FS":0,"sch.FM":0,"dp.HB":1,"fee.CF":0,"rcm.GL":0,"rcm.BY":0,"sch.ER":0,"sch.IJ":0,"dp.DK":1,"ls.KB":2,"sch.EY":0,"bot.GB":0,"sch.FX":4,"ord.FE":1,"sch.KV":0,"ads.AQ":1,"sch.HJ":0,"sch.GW":0,"dp.BS":0,"shopsch.CK":1,"sch.LE":0,"sch.FY":4,"sch.GQ":0,"sch.EI":0,"shopsch.DQ":2,"sch.FG":0,"sch.GO":111,"sch.EH":2,"sch.GD":0,"bot.KG":1,"sch.KQ":1,"bot.HQ":3,"bot.HS":3,"bot.KF":2,"sch.GU":0,"sch.FH":5,"sch.IC":0,"sch.HX":0,"sch.HD":1,"dp.DR":1,"sch.EA":10,"sch.DT":0,"credit.FI":0,"dp.DJ":0,"sch.IW":0,"voucher.IB":8,"bi.HP":2,"sch.FV":4,"ls.IV":1,"shopsch.CJ":1,"sch.ET":2,"sch.HG":3,"sch.HH":0,"voucher.GP":4,"dp.GH":2,"bi.IF":1,"sch.GC":0,"sch.EV":0,"sch.EB":1,"fee.BW":1,"voucher.IR":4,"ord.GY":2,"prm.AJ":0,"sch.KM":4,"shopsch.DX":18,"dp.LH":1,"sch.HI":0,"sch.EN":2,"bi.IE":1,"bot.IT":2,"bot.GI":4,"bot.KH":2,"sch.DG":1,"sch.EC":1,"foodsch.KP":0,"ls.FL":1,"dp.HM":2,"dl.CN":2,"sch.CG":0,"prm.AN":0,"sch.FB":6,"fee.AY":0,"sch.FQ":0,"fee.BA":1},"signature":"0.a.1014@DNEMJODMGEGWGCBZKNHXDTINICBYFQFGFIHIAJGGDFCFGNIODOIPHJGFERILBBGKEYCAFSGBKPBSDJGDAYGTFMKVLEIWEVCGANHHCBJQIJEZKCGLGQGAFRIZEIGU0IGJZKIIVFPLHEUAQKGDRIFFJDVBWDSBAHECJFLBXDYIEHDHBDGIXCKECDKFEIHKQEBAV1KBHPCMFZDQEHLIKHHMFCGHENEGKFESHAGYGVEPETITHNCNHOFK2HRGRHSHTHQFWHG3GIIRKMFVDPFYFNGPFX4FHID5FB6DZIB8EA10DX18GO111"}</script></link></link></link></link></link></link></link></meta></meta></meta></link></meta></head>
<body>
<noscript>
<iframe height="0" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WJZQSJF" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe>
</noscript>
<div class="app-shell">
<div class="navbar-fake" style="height:44px;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)"></div>
<style>@keyframes movement{from{transform:translateY(2px)}50%{transform:translateY(-2px)}to{transform:translateY(2px)}}.spinner circle{animation:.4s movement linear infinite}.spinner circle:nth-child(2){animation-delay:.1s}.spinner circle:nth-child(3){animation-delay:.2s}</style>
<svg class="spinner" height="12" style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)" viewbox="-1 0 33 12" width="34">
<circle class="loading-dot" cx="4" cy="6" fill="#ee4d2d" r="4"></circle>
<circle class="loading-dot" cx="16" cy="6" fill="#ee4d2d" r="4"></circle>
<circle class="loading-dot" cx="28" cy="6" fill="#ee4d2d" r="4"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>
<div class="style__modal__3qDSf98C">
<div class="style__modal__DSf2345XC">
<div class="style__apps_3RSD99">
<div class="style__fshow__2EQ5833"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript on your browser.</noscript>
<script src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/webpack-runtime.1f7ecaaf243e950acd83.js"></script>
<script src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/entry-modules.5b368a048c5908338df0.js"></script>
<script src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/modules.cae3a06e7fd68892cda3.js"></script>
<script src="https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/bundle.24388f88eeed96734c10.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```